# Getting Always Error 500 Asking with Reddit's API for Votes Count

Tags: php, json, curl, reddit

I'm using Reddit's API to get votes count for a given URL (I'm doing that like this, http://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?url=$url). I'm always getting Error 500 message. I give you a snippet of my code below. Anyone can help me?

```
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,15);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;
curl_close($ch);
```

Echo is always returning me the next line.

```
<html><body><h1>500 Server Error</h1>An internal server error occured.</body></html>
```

Thanks for reading.

**--- EDITED ---**

It is working locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

reddit's [API rules](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API) state the following about user agents:

- Change your client's User-Agent string to something unique and descriptive, preferably referencing your reddit username.

  - Example: User-Agent: super happy flair bot v1.0 by /u/spladug
  - Many default User-Agents (like "Python/urllib" or "Java") are drastically limited to encourage unique and descriptive user-agent strings.
  - If you're making an application for others to use, please include a version number in the user agent. This allows us to block buggy versions without blocking all versions of your app.
  - NEVER lie about your user-agent. This includes spoofing popular browsers and spoofing other bots. We will ban liars with extreme prejudice.

That doesn't explain the 500 error, nevertheless, this is where I'd start if the same URL works just fine when you use your browser. If you are getting 500 errors when also using your browser, then you probably aren't using the `info` API correctly (and consequently found a bug).

Comment: Any idea about how to use the username? I tried this:

curl_septopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL_USERAGENT, 'application v1.0 by /u/username');

But, as you say, this wouldn't explain the 500 error.

Comment: I'm not sure what username you are talking about. You might try outputting the final URL that you are requesting and see if it works in the browser. If it doesn't then the URL generation is the problem. My guess in that case would be that you need to URL encode the url parameter.

Comment: It is working locally. How can I know if Reddit has banned my server?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a local install of reddit that sending this request to works fine?

Comment: I mean that the same script works fine in my local machine but doesn't work in my server. I think that Reddit could have banned my server. I'm trying to contact them. Any other ideas?

Comment: We mailed Reddit several times, but they never replied us. We finished deleting this feature from our web service.